# Is there a convention on which block element should be creating the margin?

Tags: html, css

So let's say I have 2 block divs and I want to have 10px margin between them. I could do this in 3 different ways:

- The top div has `margin-bottom: 10px;`
- The bottom div has `margin-top: 10px;`
- The top div has `margin-bottom: 5px;` and the bottom div has
  `margin-top: 5px;`

All solutions will work, however, I'm wondering if there is a convention which might make it clearer which option to use, especially if I have more than 2 divs.

Comment: Not sure if this is the industry standard, but I tend to work from top to bottom and from the outside towards the inside. I do this since it fits along with the structure of the HTML and makes using the inspector easier since I have less I need to dig through when checking the styles being applied. So in this case I would say the first option.

Comment: Yep many ways to skin this one but doing it consistently is key. Some even remove the margin on last-child to get finer grain control between the last div and footer block.

Comment: I'm also fond of using option #1 and just going top to bottom.

Comment: the #3 will not necessarely be the same as #1 or #2 due to margin collapsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the grid system you use and how all other elements interact with the div. It's more important to just be consistent with the box-model elemental properties, so that it is easier to read and change at a later time.